# Add tsv file upload button to Jupyter Notebook using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, filereader

So I am using Jupyter 4.x and python 3.5, trying to "upload" a `.tsv`, but really just trying to capture it as a string and then use
    `setTimeout(function(){IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("stringData=StringIO(+"fr.result")");},5000);`

to allow time for the `FileReader()` object to complete the binary-string conversion then save the string into a python variable. I tested that the `Filereader()` was working by printing the entire `.tsv` file in the console. For some reason, though, stringData remains undefined on the python side.Here is the javascript cell:

```
%%HTML
<input type="file" id="CSVFileInput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" value="upload csv">

<script>
var inputElement=document.getElementById('CSVFileInput');
function handleFiles() {
    var file = inputElement.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsText(file);
    var outputString=fr.result;
    var command = "dataString ='"+outputString+"'";  
    setTimeout(function(){
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(command);}
        ,5000);
}
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
</script>
```

And in the next cell I test the output and get `NameError` because `dataString` is undefined, here is the next cell:

```
dataString
```

Also, I'm kind of new to javascript, so any and all advice is welcome, I only think this is the easy way. Pls? And, of course, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have made a few edits to this code trying things but still the same result, The entire `outputString` gets printed to the console if you put `console.log` inside the callback function, but `dataString` remains undefined. `readAsText()` is supposed to return `UTF-8` which should be fine for a python kernel...I have read a few things here and ther saying it might not actually be `UTF-8`, but nothing that points to what it actually is or how to prep it for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, @K3N definitely gave me a valuable piece of the puzzle and lesson in async functions. However, the main issue was that python did not recognize the string inputs it was receiving from javascript, so I thought I'd share my journey with all. I ended up converting the string to a 2d javascript array, then I `shift()` the first row off for the column names, transpose the remaining rows, and clean out all the dumb stuff from english that stops it from working (quotes and apostrophes). Now I can `pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(colNames,cols)))` and run all the calculations I run on the same `.tsv` when I read it in from my filesystem. Here is the full script, basically the fixes @K3N showed me plus the `pythonify(arr)` function:

```html
    <input type="file" id="TSVFileInput" title="upload tsv">
```

```js
function handleFiles() {
    //read in file and instantiate filereader
    let file = this.files[0];// "this" is the calling element
    let fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function() {        
        //split on row delimeter (CRLF)
        let outputBuffer = this.result.split("\r\n");  
        let command;
        // split outputBuffer into 2d array
        outputBuffer= outputBuffer.map(line => line.split("\t"));
        //pop names row from output Buffer
        let names=outputBuffer.shift();
        //optimized transpose   
        outputBuffer=outputBuffer.reduce(
            (temp,row) => 
                row.map((element,i) => 
                    (temp[i] || []).concat(element))
            ,[] //initializes temp
        );
        //build python command 
        command="colNames ="+pythonify(names);
        //send command to notebook kernel
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(command);    
        //loop appends columns on python side
        for(let i=0 ; i< outputBuffer.length ; i++){  
            command="cols.append("+pythonify(outputBuffer[i])+")";    
            IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(command);   //send command to kernel
        } 
    }; //end fr.onload()
    fr.readAsText(file); // invoked asynchronously, triggers fr.onload
}//end handleFiles()

function pythonify (arr){    
//turns javascript array into string representation of python list
    let out= '[';
    for(let i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
        var element=arr[i];
        //format double and single quotes
        element=element.replace(/\"/g,'\\"').replace(/'/g,"\\'");
        //use python raw string
        out+='r"'+element+'"';
        if(i<arr.length-1){ //skip last comma
            out+=',';
        }
    }
    out+=']';
    return out;
}// end pythonify(arr)

document.getElementById("CSVFileInput").addEventListener("change", handleFiles);
```

Answer (score 2):

`FileReader` methods are asynchronous so there is no data loaded at the time you try to set `outputString` to the result.

The proper way to handle this is to use the `load` event handler, so instead of using `setTimeout()`, which is unreliable for asynchronous handling, you can modify the code to the following:

```
function handleFiles() {
  var file = this.files[0];              // "this" is the calling element
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    var outputString = this.result;      // here the data is ready. Now "this" = fr
    var command = "dataString ='" + outputString + "'";  
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(command);
  };
  fr.readAsText(file);                   // invoked asynchronously
}
```

Also remove the inline JavaScript in the HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="CSVFileInput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" value="upload csv">
```

to

```
<input type="file" id="CSVFileInput" title="upload csv">
```

(`value` has no effect when input is `type=file`, use `title` instead). Then use the following code to take care of event handling (after the DOM has loaded):

```
document.getElementById("CSVFileInput").addEventListener("change", handleFiles);
```

```js
function handleFiles() {
  var file = this.files[0];              // "this" is the calling element
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    var outputString = this.result;      // here the data is ready. Now "this" = fr
    var command = "dataString ='" + outputString + "'";  
    //IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(command);
    console.log("Loaded file. Command:", command);
  };
  fr.readAsText(file);                   // invoked asynchronously
}

document.getElementById("CSVFileInput").addEventListener("change", handleFiles);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="CSVFileInput" title="upload csv">
```